# Show that f has another inflection point and compute the (x, y)-coordinates of this other point of inflection?

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider the function $f(x) = ax^4 − 8x^3 + b$. Assume that $(x, y) = (2, 8)$ is an inflection
point of this function. Show that f has another inflection point and compute the
$(x, y)$-coordinates of this other point of inflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inflection points occur where the second derivative changes sign: $$f(x)=ax^4-8x^3+b$$
$$f''(x)=12x(ax-4)$$ Thus, an inflection point at $x=\frac{4}{a}=2$ and one at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use $f(2)=8$ to get an equation in $a$ and $b$. Find the second derivative of $f(x)$. Solve the equation $f''(2)=0$ for a. Now find $b$. Use the now fully-determined formula for $f''(x)$ to find a solution to $f''(x)=0$ other than $x=2$. Find the $y$ value for that $x$. Show that $f''(x)$ changes sign at that value of $x$.

(Note that some of those actions can be done in a different order.)